# GROUP BY no funciona y muestra "not a single-group group function"

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo la siguiente sentencia en SQL Developer y al querer contar el número de productos por cliente, no me deja ya que al agruparlos me sale lo siguiente

> ORA-00937: la función de grupo no es de grupo único 00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function" *Cause:    *Action: Error en la línea: 1.699, columna: 20

Y la línea 1699 es esta:

> UPPER(TO_CHAR(CLI.NUMRUN,'09G999G999') || '-' || DVRUN) AS "RUN CLIENTE",

```
SELECT 
        TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1,'YYYY') AS "AÑO TRIBUTARIO",
        UPPER(TO_CHAR(CLI.NUMRUN,'09G999G999') || '-' || DVRUN) AS "RUN CLIENTE",
        INITCAP(CLI.PNOMBRE) || ' ' || SUBSTR(CLI.SNOMBRE,1,1) || '. ' || INITCAP(CLI.APPATERNO) || ' ' || INITCAP(CLI.APMATERNO) AS "NOMBRE CLIENTE",
        COUNT(PIC.NRO_SOLIC_PROD) AS "TOTAL INV"
FROM 
        CLIENTE CLI JOIN PRODUCTO_INVERSION_CLIENTE PIC
        ON(CLI.NRO_CLIENTE = PIC.NRO_CLIENTE)
WHERE
        PIC.COD_PROD_INV IN (30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55);
GROUP BY
        "AÑO TRIBUTARIO",
        "RUN CLIENTE",
        "NOMBRE CLIENTE";
```

Comment: Estás usando una función de agregación (`COUNT`)... ¿Y el GROUP BY?

Comment: @padaleiana Disculpa, allí está bien y completo, olvidé añadirlo en el código de la pregunta.

Comment: No podés agrupar por los alias...

Comment: @padaleiana ¿Qué hago en ese caso? Ya que tengo muchos campos en las tres primeras selecciones, no sé cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Simplemente remover lo que hay desde "AS" para adelante, en cada columna del SELECT. De última, te creás un CTE y hacés el COUNT y el GROUP BY a partir del CTE. Acá podés encontrar [lo que es un CTE](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/using-common-table-expressions/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los "alias" de columna son una de las últimas cosas que resuelve el interprete SQL, no es lo último, por que lo es el `ORDER BY` (los alias suelen funcionar en esta sentencia). En tú caso lo que ocurre es que para el motor, al menos en el momento de procesar el `GROUP BY` no existe `"AÑO TRIBUTARIO"`, ni los otros alías, por lo que en definitiva estás agrupando por una cadena cualquiera, no la columna, por lo que el error te dice que la función `COUNT()` con columnas sin agrupar no es válida. Hay dos alterntivas que puedes probar:

#### Repetir las columnas en el `GROUP BY`

```
GROUP BY
        TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1,'YYYY'),
        UPPER(TO_CHAR(CLI.NUMRUN,'09G999G999') || '-' || DVRUN),
        INITCAP(CLI.PNOMBRE) || ' ' || SUBSTR(CLI.SNOMBRE,1,1) || '. ' || INITCAP(CLI.APPATERNO) || ' ' || INITCAP(CLI.APMATERNO)
```

#### Usar una subconsulta

De esta forma, materializas los nombres de columna antes de `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT  "AÑO TRIBUTARIO",
        "RUN CLIENTE",
        "NOMBRE CLIENTE",
        COUNT(NRO_SOLIC_PROD) AS "TOTAL INV"
        FROM (
            SELECT  PIC.NRO_SOLIC_PROD,
                    TO_CHAR(SYSDATE - 1,'YYYY') AS "AÑO TRIBUTARIO",
                UPPER(TO_CHAR(CLI.NUMRUN,'09G999G999') || '-' || DVRUN) AS "RUN CLIENTE",
                INITCAP(CLI.PNOMBRE) || ' ' || SUBSTR(CLI.SNOMBRE,1,1) || '. ' || INITCAP(CLI.APPATERNO) || ' ' || INITCAP(CLI.APMATERNO) AS "NOMBRE CLIENTE"
                FROM CLIENTE CLI JOIN PRODUCTO_INVERSION_CLIENTE PIC
                    ON(CLI.NRO_CLIENTE = PIC.NRO_CLIENTE)
                WHERE PIC.COD_PROD_INV IN (30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55)
        )
        GROUP BY
            "AÑO TRIBUTARIO",
            "RUN CLIENTE",
            "NOMBRE CLIENTE";
```

Nota: Conceptualmente similar a una subconsulta, tienes las [COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-en/with.html#common-table-expressions)

Comment: Buenas, entendí bien la teoría de su respuesta, la llevé al sql developer para probar, pero me sale identificador invalido el COUNT(PIC.NRO_SOLIC_PROD) :(

Comment: Revisa mi edición, faltaba agregar `PIC.NRO_SOLIC_PROD` a la subconsulta

Comment: Muchas gracias Patricio, logré lo que quería hacer de un modo más convencional, pero agregar tu conocimiento con relación a las subconsultas a mi arsenal es totalmente bienvenido, un saludo!